# HIVE - Error loading twitter JSON data

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hive path =`/usr/local/hive/`

Hadoop path = `/usr/local/hadoop/`

Hadoop version = 2.6.0

Hive version = 2.3.2

I have added .jar in `/lib` directory of both paths and HDFS in `/input`

Download link = [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByJLBTmJojjzMlhUWGxVMWtXdEU) (hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT)

I added the .jar file in Hive shell `add jar /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;`

While creating an external table to store the data from the JSON file, I get the following error

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE twitter(id BIGINT,text STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/input/';
```

[Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KViLZ.png)

LOG FILE -

```
> 2018-01-24T19:57:40,386  INFO [e81a3c51-48a3-49e9-8121-e50b1ca97a90 main] ql.Driver: Executing command(queryId=infoobjects_20180124195740_04de95b6-9188-4b4e-9561-66c9db233cb9): create external table twitter(id BIGINT,text STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/input/'
2018-01-24T19:57:40,387  INFO [e81a3c51-48a3-49e9-8121-e50b1ca97a90 main] ql.Driver: Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
2018-01-24T19:57:40,388 ERROR [e81a3c51-48a3-49e9-8121-e50b1ca97a90 main] exec.DDLTask: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.validateSerDe(DDLTask.java:4213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.CreateTableDesc.toTable(CreateTableDesc.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 40 more
2018-01-24T19:57:40,388 ERROR [e81a3c51-48a3-49e9-8121-e50b1ca97a90 main] ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
```

I apologize for any mistake, it's my first question here (as I couldn't find a solution on the net). Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Ali's(accepted) answer worked for me. In addition, I also had to re-format my JSON to contain single line JSON objects.

Comment: There are multiple similar questions in the stack with no accepted answers. As the exception is class not found, I would suggest few thing to check, one is to check if the jar file has proper permissions or not and then I would suggest you to add the jar from hive/beeline shell before executing the DDL.

Comment: "I added the .jar file in Hive"... Where and how?

Comment: @rob Exactly my reason to post the question. I tried both the options, same issue. (adding jar from shell and .jar permissions)

@cricket_007 (from the hive shell) `add jar /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;`

Comment: Hey @VarunChaudhary did you find a solution to your problem? As I have a similar issue

Comment: @Ali Nope. I tried all that I found on the internet with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.

Starting from Hive 0.12 it come with a built-in

> JsonSerDe (Hive 0.12 and later in hcatalog-core).

All the serde we were using are not compatible with the versions we use (in my case Hive 2.3.2)

You can add the jar corresponding to your version `add jar HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-2.3.2.jar` and then on your query change 'com.cloudera....' by

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thou art a savior! Thanks a lot, @Ali.

Comment: Dear Ali & Varun I too had similar problems but I solved it by using jar and serde suggested by you but after creating table when I run select * from query it gave me error as `SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException` My data is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=17dmK6eBaiVxqEOvnLkmVYlnyKNZgUTFU I think  it is because     Invalid Json.How to rectify this.Please Help! as I have to show this use case to my boss and I already spent 3 days after it.

Comment: sorry I missed your comment. how did you get this file? using Flume? you can validate json format using this site http://jsonparseronline.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have same error with you, but when i modify to "ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'", It has succeed but when i select * from tables; this only show empty table; "hive> SELECT count(*) FROM tweets;
OK
0"